# how to using multi-processor ActionResult asp.net mvc 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multiprocessing, actionresult

The controller has many `ActionResult` and when I click on View, one of them called and run. While I click on the View, ActionResult called will have to wait before it completes `ActionResult` then run.
I want to call my 2nd ActionResult both 2 and parallel action.

Is there a way to realize it not ??

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense.  Perhaps showing some code and detailing what's not working, and what you expect to see?

Answer (score -1):

```
public ActionResult DownLoad(){
// do somethings
return File ( ... );
}

public ActionResult UpLoad(){
// do somethings
return View ( ... );
}
```

When I called action `Download`, it is running.
I want to call `UpLoad` to run parallel with `Download` and return somethings.

Or  calling two actions `Download` and runnning them parallel .

Comment: In what context?  If you have two users call both actions simultaneously, the web server will process both requests at the same time.

Comment: Really ? IIS not run both requests at the same time. 2nd action wait 1st action finish and run after.

Comment: Yes really.  Otherwise how do websites support more than one user?  You'll need to show us, or tell us, how you are invoking these requests and coming to this conclusion.

Comment: Now, I want to download a file using action Download and create a progress bar in a View. If web server support multi-process,the controller don't have multi-process. How to run Download action and return data to progress bar in View and Download action cont' ?